# PHP how to set color to certain keywords (text) in scraped data

Tags: php, xpath, colors, scrape

Trying to do something a bit tricky, where I set a color for given keywords for an echo, that is gathered from web scraping. I was given an answer once, but unable to get it to actually change any colors. Here's the code I'm working with.

```
 <?php 

$doc = new DOMDocument;

// djia/nas/sp current values
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// Most HTML Developers are chimps and produce invalid markup...
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;

$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.nbcnews.com/business');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//div[@class='market']";

$entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
echo trim($entry->textContent);  // use `trim` to eliminate spaces

}

?>
```

It's spitting out this result: DJIA 21271.97 +89.44(0.42%)NASDAQ 6207.92 -113.85(-1.80%)S&P 500 2431.77 -2.02(-0.08%)

How could I format it to always color the word for ex, DJIA, as red? I understand the logic of what would have to happen, but not sure how to make it work with my existing code.

I was supplied with this as an answer once, but again it didn't actually change the color of "DJIA." Perhaps someone out there knows what I was doing wrong possibly? *Remember this is scraped text I'm dealing with here.

```
<?php 

$doc = new DOMDocument;

// djia/nas/sp current values
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// Most HTML Developers are chimps and produce invalid markup...
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;

$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.nbcnews.com/business');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//div[@class='market']";

$entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    if(trim($entry->textContent) =='DJIA'){//compare with the word you want 
to make red
 echo "<span style='color:red;'>". trim($entry->textContent) ."
</span>";
    }else{
        echo trim($entry->textContent);
    }
 }

?>
```

Thanks for any feedback!!

Comment: It looks like the problem here is that your if statement is looking to see if the entire textContent is only DJIA, but there is other stuff in textContent.

Answer (score 1):

`strreplace('DJIA', '<span class="color:red">DJIA</span>', $someText);`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any advice about placing that into the existing code I have? If there's something I should replace it with, don't want to break the php. I'm super new to this language

Comment: <?php 
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    // djia/nas/sp current values
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    // Most HTML Developers are chimps and produce invalid markup...
    $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;

Comment: $doc->recover = true;
    $doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.nbcnews.com/business');
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $query = "//div[@class='market']";
    $entries = $xpath->query($query);
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        if(trim($entry->textContent) =='DJIA'){//compare with the word you want to make red
        strreplace('DJIA', '<span class="color:red">DJIA</span>', $someText);
        }else{
            echo trim($entry->textContent);
        }
    }
?>

Comment: Tried placing it there, wasn't the solution though obviously. My attempt anyway.

Comment: Sorry, no. If I did that it wouldn't really be answering a question and I would just be doing your work for you for free. If you look at my comment in response to your question it should point you in the right direction, but it seems like you are out of your depth and need to hire a programmer.