# PHP How to control echo'd scraped data with css

Tags: php, css, xpath, scrape

Trying to getter at PHP scraping. Dealing with this test coding, which is giving me this result: NASDAQ Composite All-Time Record-High Close: June 8, 2017 (6,321.76)

But, I'm looking to step up my scraping game a bit, and learn how to actually control that text via css. I've seen some content before that looks like people assigning certain echo'd text "keywords," which css then uses as an identifier, but I've never been able to get that working. Any thoughts on how to say...specifically control the word NASDAQ? With the below coding I'm working with. *I know how to do css fine, php is where I'm struggling.

```
 $doc = new DOMDocument;

//nas all time high
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// Most HTML Developers are chimps and produce invalid markup...
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;

$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.fedprimerate.com/nasdaq-composite-history-
chart.htm');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//p[contains(text(),'Record')]";

$entries = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
echo trim($entry->textContent);  // use `trim` to eliminate spaces

}
?>
```

I appreciate any thoughts or examples as I'm very new to php. Thank you!!

Comment: What's the difference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512373/php-how-to-set-color-to-certain-keywords-text-in-scraped-data? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491973/php-setting-colors-for-certain-text-words-in-echo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP how to set color to certain keywords (text) in scraped data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512373/php-how-to-set-color-to-certain-keywords-text-in-scraped-data)

Comment: Maybe there's not, I meant just more generally. Before, it seemed like the approach was trying to change it directly in the PHP. I'm just trying to see methods of doing any change in CSS, then working from there.

Comment: `preg_replace` comes to mind